# How do I prevent people from overloading a socket node.js server from inspector?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a website that counts the total number of clicks that users do when they click a button. When a button is clicked, it emits a 'Press' to the server which ups the clicks variable by 1. However, people can just go into the inspector and type a for loop like

```
for(var i =0; i <10000; i++){
    socket.emit('Press');
}
```

and it will just mess up the count. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Essentially: no. You can make it harder, but you can't make it totally impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't. You can stop some or slow them down, but there are always going to be workarounds.

Long(er) answer:
There are a couple ways to prevent people from doing something like this. Although there are ways around them, they might work. The first is `debugger` loops. These won't work in all browsers, but will stop execution of any code until you manually continue. They might look like this, just located where you already have something that repeats:

```js
while (true) {
debugger;
}
```

Another way would be to hide all of your code inside a function (probably an IIFE). That makes it inaccessible from the `window` object.

```js
(function() {
console.log("I'm hidden!");
})();
```

You can also obfuscate or minify your code to make it harder to understand.

All of these methods can be bypassed. `debugger` loops won't work if the console isn't open. Since you can execute JavaScript in other ways, this won't always work. A browser extension could replace your script and make anything inside it available on the `window` object. And obfuscation only slows people down.

**However**:
You have not fallen victim to the XY problem. You asked about the problem, not the solution. As a result, you can achieve your goal server-side. Simply cut off the connection if you receive too many messages too quickly. Just make sure you don't accidentally close benign connections.

Comment: Uh, a debugger loop *will* run even if the console is not open. It won't *pause* the execution via the developer tools but is still an infinite busy wait that will hog the UI thread and thus kill your website.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I mentioned it should go in an existing loop.

Comment: Or, better yet, make it run whenever a message is sent

Comment: Oh, I was hoping for some way to definitively prevent cheating the system. I thought a server gave you all the control over what could come in. Is there even a way to check if the clicks are coming in too fast from an area? What if a real user was really good at clicking or a lot of people clicked all at once?

Comment: Wait but how does this website do it? https://clickspeedtest.com/. If execute this code in the console nothing happens: for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){document.getElementById("clicker").click();}

Comment: @JamesHuang try `clicker.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))`